# Was sage Aitareya born out of Shudra woman?

Tags: caste-system

In one of online answers I've found sage Aitareya who wrote Aitareya Upanishad was born out of Shudra woman! 
Can anyone give reference to support or reject this claim?

Comment: But people usually consider only the varna of father. Mother is not significant for them. there are other examples like satyakama jabali etc.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi a son of Sudra mother is Sudra according to Manu Smriti. ( Though in actual outcaste )

Comment: "In one of online answers" -- Can you edit and post that link in the question? Even better if you use a blockquote and quote the relevant part.